# Check if white space exists before opening and closing parenthesis

Tags: c#

My string could have multiple open and close parenthesis and want to check that it is grammatically correct before we use such a string for email distribution. Strings come from vendors.

If there is no space before and/or after I want to add a white space.

Currently the code goes through and checks or all `(` and checks if the character at `index-1` is a white space and if not adds it and then it does similar for `)`.

This is one of the vendor code we were given and were told that it works as the strings would be a max of 40 characters.

Can I check and add space using regex? I looked at SO and have not found anything so far, found articles which use Regex to extract text from within certain characters.

Comment: What about if the opening parenthesis is at the beginning of the line?  You still want to add a space before?

Comment: Can you show an example of such string?

Comment: So what's supposed to happen if after adding a space before and after a left/right parentheses the string exceeds 40 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combination of Non Regex to insert spaces, and Regex to reduce 2 spaces to 1 space

```
string text = " ( ( (abc ) def)ghi)";
text = Regex.Replace(text.Replace("(", " ( ").Replace(")", " ) "), @"[ ]{2,}", @" ");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Here's a little cleaner with one `String.Replace()` & one `Regex.Replace()`

```
string text = " ( ((abc ) def)ghi)";
text = Regex.Replace(text.Replace(" ", String.Empty), "\\w+|[()]", "$0 ");

Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Results:

```
 (  (  ( abc ) def ) ghi )
```

### UPDATE

The performance between `Regex` and non `Regex` has been on my mind all day, so I decide to test the two samples I've already provided against pure non `Regex` methods.

You'll see in the code below that `InsertSpaces1()` is my first sample and `InsertSpaces2()` is my second sample.  `InsertSpaces3()` & `InsertSpaces4()` and pure non `Regex` methods of inserting spaces before and after parentheses.  `InsertSpaces3()` holds the data in a `StringBuilder`, while `InsertSpaces4()` holds the data in a `string`.  It turns out on average that `InsertSpaces4()` is the fastest way to achieve the results even though it may not be the most memory efficient since new strings are being generated with each `Insert()` call. `InsertSpaces3()` comes in second place, but is probably more efficient regarding memory usage.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        InsertSpaces1();
        InsertSpaces2();
        InsertSpaces3();
        InsertSpaces4();
    }

    private static void InsertSpaces1()
    {
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        w.Start();

        string text = " ( ((abc ) def)ghi)";
        text = Regex.Replace(text.Replace("(", " ( ").Replace(")", " ) "), @"[ ]{2,}", @" ");
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void InsertSpaces2()
    {
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        w.Start();

        string text = " ( ((abc ) def )ghi)";
        text = Regex.Replace(text.Replace(" ", String.Empty), "\\w+|[()]", "$0 ");
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void InsertSpaces3()
    {
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        w.Start();

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("( ((abc ) def )ghi)");
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (
                // Insert a space to the left even at the beginning of the string
                (text[i] == '(' && ((i - 1 >= 0 && text[i - 1] != ' ') || i == 0)) ||
                (text[i] == ')' && ((i - 1 >= 0 && text[i - 1] != ' ') || i == 0))
               )
            {
                text.Insert(i, ' ');
            } 
            else if (
                     // Insert a space to the right
                     (text[i] == '(' && (i + 1 < text.Length && text[i + 1] != ' ')) ||
                     (text[i] == ')' && (i + 1 < text.Length && text[i + 1] != ' '))
                    )
            {
                text.Insert(i + 1, ' ');
            }
            else if (
                     // Insert a space to the right even at the end
                     (text[i] == '(' && (i + 1 == text.Length)) ||
                     (text[i] == ')' && (i + 1 == text.Length))
                    )
            {
                text.Append(" ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    }

    private static void InsertSpaces4()
    {
        Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
        w.Start();

        string text = "( ((abc ) def )ghi)";
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (
                // Insert a space to the left even at the beginning of the string
                (text[i] == '(' && ((i - 1 >= 0 && text[i - 1] != ' ') || i == 0)) ||
                (text[i] == ')' && ((i - 1 >= 0 && text[i - 1] != ' ') || i == 0))
               )
            {
                text = text.Insert(i, " ");
            } 
            else if (
                     // Insert a space to the right
                     (text[i] == '(' && (i + 1 < text.Length && text[i + 1] != ' ')) ||
                     (text[i] == ')' && (i + 1 < text.Length && text[i + 1] != ' '))
                    )
            {
                text = text.Insert(i + 1, " ");
            }
            else if (
                     // Insert a space to the right even at the end
                     (text[i] == '(' && (i + 1 == text.Length)) ||
                     (text[i] == ')' && (i + 1 == text.Length))
                    )
            {
                text += " ";
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        w.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
 ( ( ( abc ) def ) ghi ) 
00:00:00.0000383
( ( ( abc ) def ) ghi ) 
00:00:00.0000333
 ( ( ( abc ) def ) ghi ) 
00:00:00.0000114
 ( ( ( abc ) def ) ghi ) 
00:00:00.0000080
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/21IRX9

Comment: If a space already exists this solution will add spaces so more than one spaces will exist.

Comment: Or i could delete all white space before and after parans and then add them in again, not elegant but does the job

Comment: @GeorgeChond Update for that scenario

Comment: You're creating a new string every time you call 'Replace' if you care about memory usage

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  If there's two next to each other, you'll get two spaces though.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Run();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            this.Attempt("");
            this.Attempt("(");
            this.Attempt(")");
            this.Attempt("()");
            this.Attempt("( ");
            this.Attempt(" )");
            this.Attempt("( )");
            this.Attempt(" ( ");
            this.Attempt(" ( ( ");
        }

        private void Attempt(string original)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("'" + original + "' => '" + this.Replace(original) + "'" );
        }

        private string Replace(string original)
        {
            string regex = @"(\s*(\)|\()\s*)";

            Regex replacer = new Regex(regex);
            string replaced = replacer.Replace(original, " $2 ");

            return replaced;
        }
```

Results:

```
'' => ''
'(' => ' ( '
')' => ' ) '
'()' => ' (  ) '
'( ' => ' ( '
' )' => ' ) '
'( )' => ' (  ) '
' ( ' => ' ( '
' ( ( ' => ' (  ( '
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
string text = " ( ((abc ) def)ghi)";

text = text.Replace("(","( ").Replace(")"," )");//Add aditional space no matter if this one already have it.

while(text.Contains("  ")){//===>To while text contains double spaces
  text = text.Replace("  "," ");//===>Replace spaces for a single space;
}
```